# Python and CSV: find a row that is given by the user and give column value

Tags: python, pandas

It consists in creating a function that searches for the name that the user will give us and we need to print his email

here is a small part of the CSV file and it is structured as this:

| Name | Email |
| --- | --- |
| mahmoud | mahmoud.123@gmail.com |
| sam | sam.123@gmail.com |

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\samer\Downloads\cvs\mail list.csv')
print (data)
df= pd.DataFrame()
df['Name1'] = input("Enter Name:")
   
for row in data:
    if row == "Name1":
        print(row)
```

I have been stuck here, i dont know how to print the email after checking if the name the user gives us exist

here's an example of the output:
if the user gives a name that is sam
the output will be sam.123@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign the Name column to the index when loading the CSV to a DataFrame and then use `.loc` to locate the name explicitly:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'./mail list.csv', index_col='Name')
name = input("Enter Name:")
email = df.loc[name, 'Email']
```

Which results in

```
sam.123@gmail.com
```

Comment: there is a problem i keep getting, when i input a name that isnt there i get key error

Comment: Sure, if the name is not in the DataFrame then you will get a key error when it attempts to look up the name. To prevent this you will have to do some checking first. The most rudimentary check you can implement is `if name in df`, since the `Name` is set to the index and this checks the value entered against the index of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Admitting all your names in Name column are unique :

```
def get_email(df, name):
    email_list = list(df.loc[df["Name"] == name]["Email"])
    
    if email_list:
        print(email_list[0])
    else:
        print("User does not exist")

get_email(df, "sam")

[Out] : sam.123@gmail.com  

get_email(df, "Jean")

[Out] : User does not exist
```

Edit: I used this data to run the test:

```
Name    Email
mahmoud mahmoud.123@gmail.com
sam     sam.123@gmail.com
```

Comment: while i try to run this code i keep getting KeyError: 'Email'

Comment: Your column might have a slightly different name then